# Get file from res/raw folder

Tags: android, file, inputstream

I need help with File.

```
        int aIdSound=R.raw.sound;  
        String path=getString(aIdSound); // return res/raw/sound.wav

        File file=new File(path);

        if(file.exists()){
            // File doesnt exist.

        }
```

So I have tried

```
       InputStream input=getResources().openRawResource(aIdSound);
```

But I need File class, so is there any way how to change InputStream to File or any idea how to getFile by id?

Comment: what extactly u wanna do ? play sound? from raw?

Comment: create new File, copy input stream to it,  and use it ... or use library that use Streams not Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
final int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("fileName.wav", "raw", getPackageName());
```

If you are trying to play audio, you might want to investigate into MediaPlayer. Here is how I used it:

```
try {
        final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, redId);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you decide you want to use an externally saved file then you should use:

```
File fis = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "fileName" + ".wav");
Uri external = Uri.fromFile(fis);

final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, external);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read `InputStream`, write it to an external file with `FileOutputStream` to get a `File` instance of your raw resource.

Or I missed an API. :)

Answer (score 0):

Place that file in `Asserts` Folder

you can get that file using

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    // reading a assert file context.getAssets().open("filename.xml")

    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(context.getAssets().open("filename.xml"));
```

or from External Folder (SD card)

```
 try{
    // Creating Input Stream 
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename); 
    FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error in reading the file",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```